# HttpClient MaxResponseContentBufferSize is not working as expected

Tags: c#, httpclient

here is my simple code:

```
    var c = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
    c.MaxResponseContentBufferSize = 100;
    await c.GetAsync("https://stackoverflow.com/");
```

when the `MaxResponseContentBufferSize` is less than the real response size, the `GetAsync` method will not END at all.

I need if the response is more than the given `MaxResponseContentBufferSize`, it stops the request. where is the problem then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That `s because of this code  when GetAsync executed

```
private MemoryStream CreateMemoryStream(long maxBufferSize, out Exception error)
{
    error = null;
    long? contentLength = Headers.ContentLength;
    if (contentLength.HasValue)
    {
        if (contentLength > maxBufferSize)
        {
             error = new HttpRequestException(SR.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, SR.net_http_content_buffersize_exceeded, maxBufferSize));
            return null;
        }
        return new LimitMemoryStream((int)maxBufferSize, (int)contentLength.Value);
    }
    return new LimitMemoryStream((int)maxBufferSize, 0);
}
```

The result is fine [image: See The Result]

Comment: thank you, but it will not return any results. It will stay on GetAsync forever, how to end the request?

Comment: Please put your code completely because this 3 lines code don`t have problem